# How to run a suspend function inside another one without waiting for its result?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I have a scenario where my code has to send an api call and move on with its work (which contains another api call) without waiting for the result of the first call.

Right now I do this in my viewmodel

```
fun showItem(id:Int) {
   launch{
       repo.markItemRead(id)
   }
   launch {
       try {
           val item = repo.getItemById(id).getOrThrow
           commands.postValue(ShowItemCommand(item))
       } catch (t:Throwable) {
           commands.postValue(ShowError(R.string.error_retrieve_item))
           repo.logError(t)
       }
   }
}
```

this calls the repository which has these two functions

```
suspend fun markItemRead(id) {
    try {
        service.markItemAsRead(id)
    } catch(ignored:Throwable) {
    }
}

suspend fun getItemById(id) : Result<ItemData> {
    return try {
       val response : ItemEntity = service.getItemById(id)
       val item  = response.toData()
       Result.Success(item)
    } catch (t:Throwable) {
        Result.Failure(t)
    }
}
```

I would prefer it if the repository did all those jobs because one has to follow the other every time.

Unfortunatelly when I try to do something like this in my repository:

```
suspend fun getItemById(id:Int) : Result<ItemData> {
    try {
        service.markItemAsRead(id)
    } catch(ignored:Throwable) {
    }
    return try {
       val response : ItemEntity = service.getItemById(id)
       val item  = response.toData()
       Result.Success(item)
    } catch (t:Throwable) {
        Result.Failure(t)
    }
}
```

It waits for the `markItemAsRead` function to finish before moving on

Other than defining a scope for the repository and putting the `markItemAsRead` call inside a `launch` (which I have read is incorrect to do inside a suspending function) is there another way of doing this inside the repository?

Comment: I think we can use launch() in that case.. not sure

Comment: Looking to do the same thing.  @Cruces make any progress?

Comment: if I remember correctly, I ended up passing the scope to the function and running two async runs inside the viewmodel, the method now is `fun showItem(scope:CoroutineScope, id:int)` and inside there are two `val def1 = scope.async { .... }` runs and the reply is sent after the code finishes after `def1.await()` and `def2.await` end , then retrieves the result from def2 and returns it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`coroutineScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) or [`supervisorScope`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html) in the repository, depending on your needs. Both functions are designed for parallel decomposition of work. These functions return as soon as the given block and all its children coroutines are completed.

When any child coroutine in `coroutineScope` fails, this scope fails and all the rest of the children are cancelled. Unlike `coroutineScope`, a failure of a child coroutine in `supervisorScope` does not cause this scope to fail and does not affect its other children, so a custom policy for handling failures of its children can be implemented.

Please choose what best suits your needs. Example of usage:

```
suspend fun getItemByIdAndMarkRead(id: Int) : Result<ItemData> = supervisorScope {
    launch {
        try {
            service.markItemAsRead(id)
        } catch(ignored:Throwable) { }
    }

    return@supervisorScope withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        try {
            val response : ItemEntity = service.getItemById(id)
            val item  = response.toData()
            Result.Success(item)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            Result.Failure(t)
        }
    }
}
```

`service.markItemAsRead(id)` and `service.getItemById(id)` will execute in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

> is there another way of doing this inside the repository?

No there isn't

> (which I have read is incorrect to do inside a suspending function)

It is perfectly okay to use `launch` in a suspend function for a fire and forget task

Answer (score 0):

See if the [coroutineScope](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/coroutine-scope.html) function does what you want:

> Creates a CoroutineScope and calls the specified suspend block with this scope. The provided scope inherits its coroutineContext from the outer scope, but overrides the context's Job.

```
suspend fun getItemById(id:Int) : Result<ItemData> {
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            try {
                service.markItemAsRead(id)
            } catch(ignored:Throwable) { }
        }
    }

    return try {
       val response : ItemEntity = service.getItemById(id)
       val item  = response.toData()
       Result.Success(item)
    } catch (t:Throwable) {
        Result.Failure(t)
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that will work, because when the parent scope (in the viewmodel calling the function) is cancelled it will also cancel all child scopes, but it feels a bit wrong creating a new coroutine scope each time this runs, thank you for the idea though, I'll definitely keep it in mind

Comment: You want to launch another separate job to do another task without blocking. That requires that job to run in a scope. But you don't want to pass through and use the current scope. How else do you expect to do what you want without creating a new one then?

Comment: that what I was hoping to find out :), I was wondering if there is a way for an async to run on the parent's scope because it is declared in an suspending function, without having to define a child coroutine scope, as I said I know yours is the (currently) correct way, I still don't like creating new scopes though, I get the feeling that it adds too much overhead

Comment: Please provide evidence / data / stats to backup your "feeling that it adds too much overhead". Also explain how you define "overhead". I'd be interested in your findings considering that this method is explicitly called out in the documentation as how to run concurrent tasks, as you are trying to do: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder-and-concurrency

Answer (score -1):

you want to do multiple tasks in parallel but return function when all tasks done. if i'm right.

you can use async/await. inside suspend function

```
val d1 = async { t1() }
val d2 = async { t2() }
d1.await()
d2.await()
// all tasks done
```

t1 and t2 will be run in parallel. when t1.await() calls it's gonna wait for result but t2 still running.

in your function you can change it like this:

```
suspend fun getItemById(id:Int) : Result<ItemData> = coroutineScope {
    val t1 = async {
        try {
            service.markItemAsRead(id)
        } catch(ignored:Throwable) {
            null
        }
    }
    val t2 = async {
        try {
            val response : ItemEntity = service.getItemById(id)
            val item = response.toData()
            Result.Success(item)
        } catch (t:Throwable) {
            Result.Failure(t)
        }
    }
    t1.await()
    return@coroutineScope t2.await()
}
```

Comment: no I want to run one task without waiting for a response and run another by waiting, but either way async requires a coroutine scope, I would like to avoid having to define a coroutine scope or passing the view model's coroutine scope to my repository